# How to get from Split to Sarajevo?

Tags: tickets, buses, croatia, bosnia

I'm looking for a bus (rail is probably not an option) between Split and Sarajevo. What is the time schedule for these buses and how much do they cost?

Comment: Why is rail not an option?  The last time I wanted to travel from Split to Sarajevo, I caught a bus from Split to Ploče and a train from Ploče to Sarajevo.  It was far more enjoyable than catching a bus the entire way.

Comment: If bus+rail is faster/comparable to direct bus all the way, feel free to post your answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this from http://www.buscroatia.com/split-sarajevo/

> **Bus id** - ID-862
>
> **Times**-     14:30 - 20:15
>
> **Company**-    Linvo Bus
>
> **Price Single/Return** - 168 HRK / 269 HRK

Hope it helps.